# PHP Getting Id Of Submit Button in Next Page

Tags: php, post, get

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

         echo "<form name=frm  action=edit.php method=POST";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Sl_no"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["nam"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["age"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["dob"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["gender"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["married"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["temp_addr"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["fix_addrs"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["email"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["phone"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["mother_tounge"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["nationality"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["clg"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["sem"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["grad"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["qual"]. " </td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row["branch"]. " </td>";
       echo "<td> <input type=submit name =" .$row["Sl_no"]. " value =Edit  ><input type=button id=d".$row["Sl_no"]." value=Delete />";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo"</form>";
    }
```

I am using this code 
and in each field there will be a random named submit will generate. 
I want to transfer the name of the button to next page or pass the value of first  tag help me.

Answer (score 1):

On the next page you can use $_POST['key']; or $_GET['key']. That will give you access to your value from the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can not post submit button value by using name attribute. just add one hidden field with this form. like

```
echo "<td> <input type=hidden value=" .$row["Sl_no"]. " name=submit_btn_val >"
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy For Helping  ME ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value from database to the submit button value, instead of name if you want to get the value on POST, because on post you're getting the name as key and value from input as values, like this:

```php
<input type=submit name="name_here" value ="<?php echo $row['Sl_no']; ?>"  >
```